Extend hard drive on Ubuntu (Server)
Im helping a friend with his small, self-hosted Ubuntu server. He wanted to install a larger hard drive. That's why I used Clonezilla to clone the HDD to a larger SSD so that the server doesn't have to be set up from scratch. This worked great, but of course the operating system doesn't use the new storage space just like that. I tried using a bootable gparted USB stick to enlarge the operating system partition from ‘outside’. But somehow the memory in the operating system remains unchanged.
I uploaded to screenshots to imgur: One from gparted (i enlarged the dev/sda3/ Partition)and one from inside Ubuntu, using df -h --total and for some strange Reason it shows completly different partitions. Can you help me and tell me how to enlarge the Partition for the Ubuntu Server?

It has LVM therefore you must use LVM tools to manage the volumes.

On that system, /dev/sda3 is an LVM PV. After enlarging it, you'll need to extend the LV's too. There's only one LV in your df screenshot: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv. If you want to give all the free space in that VG to it, then run lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv as root. If you want to only extend that LV by some smaller amount, then do lvextend -r -L newsize /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv instead, substituting the actual new size you want for newsize.

Worked like a charm, thank you very much! Console output was "Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 200.00 GiB (51200 extents) to 1.86 TiB (487994 extents)" - but when i type df -h it says that /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  is only 267G - do you know why i dont have more space on the PV?

@DWA Did you remember the -r for the lvextend command? Also, when you do mount, what kind of filesystem is on your LV?
